# StatsModels.jl: Exponential formulas `formula(y ~ (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)^2` in Julia

Tags: r, julia

I've been trying to replicate this matrix (`R`) in `Julia`

```r
data = read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TJhon/158daa0c2dd06010d01a72dae2af8314/raw/61df065c98ec90b9ea3b8598d1996fb5371a64aa/rnd.csv")

head(model.matrix(y ~ (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)^2, data), 3)
#>   (Intercept)         x1         x2         x3        x4 x5       x1:x2
#> 1           1 -0.3007225 -1.3710894  0.3423409  1.322547  2  0.41231744
#> 2           1  0.4674170  0.8728939  0.9534157 -1.007083  1  0.40800548
#> 3           1  0.2085316 -0.3657995 -0.3043694 -1.036938  4 -0.07628076
#>         x1:x3      x1:x4      x1:x5      x2:x3      x2:x4      x2:x5      x3:x4
#> 1 -0.10294961 -0.3977198 -0.6014450 -0.4693799 -1.8133307 -2.7421787  0.4527620
#> 2  0.44564276 -0.4707279  0.4674170  0.8322308 -0.8790769  0.8728939 -0.9601690
#> 3 -0.06347064 -0.2162343  0.8341265  0.1113382  0.3793113 -1.4631979  0.3156121
#>        x3:x5     x4:x5
#> 1  0.6846817  2.645095
#> 2  0.9534157 -1.007083
#> 3 -1.2174775 -4.147751
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I tried the

```
using CSV, DataFrames, StatsModels, StatsBase

data = CSV.read(download("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TJhon/158daa0c2dd06010d01a72dae2af8314/raw/61df065c98ec90b9ea3b8598d1996fb5371a64aa/rnd.csv"), DataFrame) 

ModelMatrix(ModelFrame(@formula(y ~ (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5) * (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)), data)).m

9×31 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  -0.300723  -1.37109    0.342341   1.32255   2.0  0.090434    0.412317   -0.10295    -0.39772    …   0.452762    1.74913     2.64509   -0.601445  -2.74218    0.684682   2.64509    4.0
 1.0   0.467417   0.872894   0.953416  -1.00708   1.0  0.218479    0.408005    0.445643   -0.470728      -0.960169    1.01422    -1.00708    0.467417   0.872894   0.953416  -1.00708    1.0

 1.0   0.395908  -1.15159   -0.204683  -0.207952  2.0  0.156743   -0.455924   -0.0810355  -0.0823297      0.0425641   0.0432439  -0.415903   0.791816  -2.30318   -0.409365  -0.415903   4.0
```

```
ModelMatrix(ModelFrame(@formula(y ~ (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5) & (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)), data)).m

9×26 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  0.090434    0.412317   -0.10295    -0.39772    -0.601445   0.412317   1.87989   -0.46938   -1.81333    …   0.452762    1.74913     2.64509   -0.601445  -2.74218    0.684682   2.64509    4.0   
 1.0  0.218479    0.408005    0.445643   -0.470728    0.467417   0.408005   0.761944   0.832231  -0.879077      -0.960169    1.01422    -1.00708    0.467417   0.872894   0.953416  

 1.0  0.156743   -0.455924   -0.0810355  -0.0823297   0.791816  -0.455924   1.32616    0.235711   0.239475       0.0425641   0.0432439  -0.415903   0.791816  -2.30318   -0.409365  -0.415903   4.0
```

```
ModelMatrix(ModelFrame(@formula(y ~ (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)^2), data)).m

9×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0   3.97235
 1.0   5.22874
 :     :
 1.0   0.691696
```

I want the same array and vector of variable names to convert it to a data frame later.

Answer (score 3):

```
xs = term.((Symbol("x$i") for i=1:5))
ff = vcat(term(1), xs, [xs[a] & xs[b] for a in 1:5 for b in a+1:5])
ModelMatrix(ModelFrame(FormulaTerm(Term(:y),Tuple(ff)), data)).m
```

works, but is uglier than R version. Perhaps there is a better way.

And also:

```
varnames = vcat("(intercept)", ["x$i" for i=1:5], ["x$(a):x$(b)" for a in 1:5 for b in a+1:5])
```

UPDATE

The above solution (while working) isn't particularly nice or Julian, therefore here is a rewrite which tries to be more generic:

```
using CSV, DataFrames, StatsModels, StatsBase

URL = join([
  "https:","","gist.githubusercontent.com",
  "TJhon","158daa0c2dd06010d01a72dae2af8314",
  "raw","61df065c98ec90b9ea3b8598d1996fb5371a64aa","rnd.csv"],
  '/')

data = CSV.read(download(URL), DataFrame) 

using Combinatorics

subsets(X; from=0, upto=length(X)) =
  Iterators.flatten(combinations(X,i) for i=max(0,from):min(upto,length(X)))

xs = term.((Symbol("x$i") for i=1:5))

term_vec = collect(subsets(xs; from=1, upto=2))
rhs = vcat(ConstantTerm(1), map(x->reduce(&, x), term_vec))
rhs_names = vcat("(intercept)", [join(string.(x),'*') for x in term_vec])

ModelMatrix(ModelFrame(FormulaTerm(Term(:y),Tuple(rhs)), data)).m
```

It looks longer, but the initial bit is just for copy-paste ease, and it has the benefit of allowing three-term interactions simply by substituting the `upto=2` with `upto=3` in the `term_vec` definition.

In particular, the `subsets` iterator should be very useful in many situations and is good idea to add to Iterators (comment if in agreement).